# getting top talked about pages on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have been searching for a way to get the top most talked about public pages on facebook so that I could have an app which could see how the results correlated with articles from other major news venders.

So far I have been completely stumped by the problem of how to get a list of the top most talked about pages using the facebook API.

I have tried using types of FQL queries but because the FQL queries on the page table can't be indexed by the number of users talking about it data so it doesn't seem like FQL will work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I should look next to try to get the most talked about pages?